# PayPal Payments Pro and Future Payments

Tags: magento, paypal

I have a case where I need customer to check out on website but not bill them for 60-90 days. Using Magento and PayPal Payments Pro. I understand PayPal auth only lasts for 30 days - how do I set up future billing on an account. Customers are pre-paying for distributions that happen 2-3 months after being announced.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using reference transactions or billing agreements, but keep in mind that this does not guarantee that the funds will be available when you go to charge the buyer.